# Is there a conda command to hash/sign a conda package and verify while installing if the hash is correct?

Tags: python, anaconda, md5, conda, sha

I wasn't able to find any documentation on any conda API that would allow users to verify if the package that they are installing using `conda install` is correct and unaltered. For example maybe a --md5 flag during `conda install <package>` that would allow them to see if the package is indeed is the correct one. Does conda provide any such functionality?